# Sending data between two ethernet interfaces on the same box

Tags: c++, sockets, ethernet

I would like to send data between two ethernet interfaces that are connected with a crossover cable in Linux.  The two ethernet interfaces are on the same box.  I defined the ethernet interfaces to have different static ip addresses (1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8) and have been using sockets to send bytes from one IP address to the other.  I want to emphasize that I want the data to leave the box one interface of the box and get received on the other interface of the same box.  One consequence of this is that unplugging the cable would prevent communication between the client and server on the same box.

The kernel is smarter than me I guess and decides it doesn't need to send information out on the wire and routes the data directly between the sockets internally, thus negating the test.  I have tried to use SO_BINDTODEVICE to force the client to send  data out of a particular interface, but the server never sees it.  I am really stuck and this doesn't seem like it should be this difficult.

There are two entries in the route -n table

```
Dest       Gateway    Genmask        flags  metric  use  interface
1.2.3.0    0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0    U       0     0   eth0
5.6.7.0    0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0    U       0     0   eth1
```

Comment: can you ping one box from the other? the fact you are using a crossover cable should be transparent to the kernel (and everything else), but if you will need a correct hosts file (tested via ping)

Comment: @vicatcu:  Don't know what a wireshark is, so no

Comment: @Neil: There is only one box as the ethernet interfaces are on the same box.  I think I am going to edit the question to make this more apparent.

Comment: What are the interface IP addresses.  The only way you could talk across network addresses is if you are using a router.  Those two interfaces could not set each other from the network side (though the internal network statck would see both segments if you are on one computer)

Comment: @ Matthew:  Edited the question with the IP addresses I have been using, although I thought it really didn't matter too much since I am on one computer and the only "network" is the cross over cable between the two interfaces.

Comment: The problem is your "network" isn't configured in a way that could work.  Change you IP addresses as Jon-Eric suggested.  But it may still not go over the ethernet connection.  The IP stack may process the message without sending it to the physical connection.

Comment: I can get the client and server to talk to eachother when I use those IP addresses, its just that the data doesn't go out over the wire.  When I bind the socket directly to the interface with SO_BINDTODEVICE, I can't seem to get them to talk at all.

Comment: wireshark is a free packet monitoring program, you should download it, and you can capture whether your one interface is emitting packets, and whether your other interface is receiving packets. It's a fairly intuitive program and really a must for network problem troubleshooting! Just google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not communicate using IP between 1.2.3.4/24 to 5.6.7.8/24 without going though a router.  The problem is that IP can only talk to other computers in the same network segment.  To calulate the network address you need to do a logic *AND* between both the interface address and the subnet mask.  This will give you the network addresses.  If the two network addresses are different then a router will be required.  In your example you will have network address 1.2.3.0 and 5.6.7.0.  Because these are different it will will to send data.

More importantly most network stacks are smart enough to see that if both interfaces are on the same computer it will not send the data all the way to the phyical interface.  It will probably only send the message though the IP stack.  But again it would need to be vaild address for it to work.

You should even be able to test a similar setup using just loopback network devices.  (virtual network cards.)

Comment: The point is that I want the data to go out on the physical interface

Comment: Again... the IP stack on the computer may not send data between the physical interfaces.  It should resolve internally that it has both address on it's own system and not even get the IP Packet to the network interface cards.

Comment: I am accepting this as I am pretty well convinced that you can't make a box go through the physical interface without changing some fundamental pieces of the system.  Guess I just didn't realize how standardized this OSI model stuff is :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following two IP addresses:

- 192.168.64.1
- 192.168.64.2

I'm not sure this is the problem, but 1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8 aren't on the same subnet. (Because when you apply the mask to each one, you don't get the same network address, as the Dest column is showing you.)

Comment: Tried using those IP addresses and there was no change.